# Oracle SQL REGEXP to replace a particular string with different column value

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string value in ColumnA separated by '_'.

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1_2_AB34-E1 | 8 |
| 2_3_CD56-F1 | 9 |

I need to modify ColumnA by replacing the value after 2nd '_' with the value in ColumnB

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1_2_8 | 8 |
| 2_3_9 | 9 |

I tried using `REGEXP_REPLACE(ColumnA, '[^|]+', ColumnB, 1, 3)`. But it is not working as expected. Can someone share their inputs?

Comment: Will the string in Column A always have exactly two underscores? Can there be more sometimes? More importantly, can there be **less** than two? How does the requirement change in those cases?

Comment: The string in Column A will always have two underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every input string has at least two underscores, and that everything after the second underscore must be replaced, you can do this much more efficiently than with regular expressions - use standard string functions instead.

```
select substr(columnA, 1, instr(columnA, '_', 1, 2)) || columnB
from   ...
```

(or use similar in `update`). `instr` returns the position of the *second* underscore in the input string in `columnA`, and then `substr` returns the substring from the first position up to and including that second underscore. Then concatenate `columnB` to that substring. The code follows the logic exactly, in every detail.

If the input string may sometimes have fewer than two underscores, you need to explain the requirement. The query above, in those cases only, will replace the **entire** string from `columnA` with the string from `columnB` - perhaps not the desired outcome. The query can be modified in those cases, to implement the required handling - while still being much more efficient than a regular expressions solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could just take everything up to the second `_` and then concatenate the other column:

```
select regexp_replace(a, '^([^_]+_[^_]+_).*', '\1') || b
```

If you want to *modify* the column in place, the logic works in an `update`:

```
update t
    set a = regexp_replace(a, '^([^_]+_[^_]+_).*', '\1') || b;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fffb105efbc7ffa177e0276642fb8ad4) is a db<>fiddle.